# Sharepoint Announcements List

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss-3.0

Is it possible to create a announcements list so that when there is no announcements, it will display a "default" announcement ?

Comment: Nevermind, found a solution, just add the following script to the default page where the list i located.

<script>
function ChangeNewMessage()
{
var a = document.getElementsByTagName('TD')
for (var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{
if (a[i].className=='ms-vb')
{
if (a[i].innerText.indexOf('There are no items to show in this view of the "Announcements" list. ')>-1)
{
a[i].innerHTML = 'Coming Soon...';
break;
}
}
}
}
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('ChangeNewMessage')
</script>

Answer (score 0):

Another non-JavaScript approach would be to use SharePoint Designer to convert the view into a DataViewWebPart.  The menuing options available in the DVWP gives an option to display text when there are no items available to display.